# Locate answer that was formerly accepted

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

I recently lost 15 reputation in SO which should mean that my answer was no longer accepted or possibly the post was deleted. When this happens will I never know what actually happened?

In the event an OP changed his marked answer, to another answer in the same post, I would like to be able to see what happened. Perhaps I can learn what I could have changed or if I maybe misunderstood the OP in that case.

Comment: You can visit chat rooms like the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask any user with 10K+ rep on SO to provide the screenshot to you

Comment: Look at the reputation tab of your profile page. Check "show removed posts" at the bottom. This should clear things up: either unaccept or post removal will be recorded there.

Comment: Go to your profile page on SO, Answers tab. You should see "deleted recent answers" in there, click it and you will probably see the deleted answer. In case the whole question was deleted you won't be able to view it though.

Comment: @lostsock is correct, I just used Jaydles as a test case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles?tab=reputation&sort=post :D